# How to give a transparent background to a fullScreen modal in react navigation (3.x)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

How to give a transparent background to a fullScreen modal in react navigation (3.x).The solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992961/react-navigation-modal-height) is not working in new version of react-navigation.
I want a transparent color in a new fullscreen modal which is presented over another screen.

```
  const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    BrowserHome: { screen: BrowserHome },
    ImageDetailModal: {
      screen: ImageDetail,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    mode: "modal",
    cardStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      opacity: 1
    }
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default AppContainer;
```

While my Image detail component which is presented over 'BrowserHome' component is:

```
export default class ImageDetail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const modalColor = this.props.navigation.getParam("modalColor");
    return (
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            height: "50%",
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "red",
            justifyContent: "center"
          }}
        >
          <Text>Testing a modal with transparent background</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you figured out how to use the transparent background? None of the answers anywhere seem to work with version 3

Comment: @Felipe In my case I used react-native-modal , however you can check the issue here https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5268

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can now remove the `cardStyle` object and set instead `transparentCard: true` :

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    BrowserHome: { screen: BrowserHome },
    ImageDetailModal: {
      screen: ImageDetail,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    mode: "modal",
    transparentCard: true
  })
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig

Comment: You can find a complete example below: https://snack.expo.io/@cristiankmb/stacks-in-tabs-with-header-options-with-modal

Answer (score 8):

## React Navigation 5x

If you updated to React Navigation version 5x, here's an update.

**Code sample**

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
    cardOverlayEnabled: true,
    cardStyleInterpolator: ({ current: { progress } }) => ({
      cardStyle: {
        opacity: progress.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 0.5, 0.9, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 0.25, 0.7, 1],
        }),
      },
      overlayStyle: {
        opacity: progress.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 0.5],
          extrapolate: 'clamp',
        }),
      },
    }),
  }}
  mode="modal"
>
  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
  <Stack.Screen name="Modal" component={ModalScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

The properties `cardOverlayEnabled` and `headerShown` here are *optionals*. It's gonna depend on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

## React Navigation 6x

Set the `screenOptions.presentation` to "transparentModal".

Comment: Recently switched to this, although I can't find any way to make the background semi-transparent (essentially blurring and darkening the underlying screen). `cardOverlayEnabled` does not work for me, do you have any idea/pointers for that?

Comment: @ThomasW I used [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal) but have you tried setting the `backgroundColor` of your scene/page container `View` to "transparent"?

Answer (score 1):

Add lines `transparentCard: true` and `cardStyle: {opacity: 1}` in createStackNavigator

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs: TabNavigator,
  Modal: ModalScreen, 
},{
  headerMode: 'none',
  mode: 'modal',
  transparentCard: true,
  cardStyle: { opacity: 1 }
});
```