# can I customize modal with navigation?

Tags: navigation, modal-dialog

I want to use the navigation, and leave the modal partially open as in print, specify a height. Does lib allow this? I did not find anything about

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you found any solutions for this? I need just the same.

Answer (score 0):

I find another solutions, for react-navigation v3.x you can use the prop transparentCard: true

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    BottomTabs: {
      screen: BottomTabsStack,
    },
    Modal: {
      screen: ModalScreen,
    }
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal',
    transparentCard: true,
    cardStyle: { opacity: 1 }
  }
);
```

You can see more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55598127/6673414

I hope that this can help you!